# Run preliminary statement in Jmeter JDBC request

Tags: jmeter, amazon-redshift

I am creating a JDBC performance test using JMeter to evaluate the performance of a set of queries on a RedShift cluster.

On RedShift, ResultSet caching is enabled by default and it can be disabled on single sessions by using the statement

```
SET enable_result_cache_for_session=false;
```

As documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_enable_result_cache_for_session.html).

I cannot find a way to run this statement in JMeter before running my queries.
If I insert it before the actual JDBC Request, JMeter complains about expecting exactly one query.

If I create in my thread group a "Once Only Controller" which is executed before running the queries (which are in a random order controller in the same thread group), its execution doesn't seem to affect caching:

Query time varies from 30 seconds for the first run to 250ms for subsequent ones.

The same happens if I try to setup a JDBC PreProcessor for each single query.

Is there a way to run this preliminary query using jmeter? Alternatively, is there a way to globally disable caching on a Redshift cluster?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer ? It is now available in JMeter 5.1 if you want to test

Answer (score 2):

You can alter this parameter using Parameter groups:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-parameter-groups.html

In JMeter <=  5.0 , it's not working as a new connection is extracted from pool on each query so the setting is not active.

I opened an enhancement request for this and we provided a fix that is now in JMeter nightly build and should be available in 5.1:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62832

Try nightly build here:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

**EDIT 21 february 2019:**

[JMeter 5.1](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) has been released with the feature.

You configure it on [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem.
Here how you can configure running "cache off" query:

1. In a "test plan" window - check the "Run Thread Groups consecutively"
2. create 2 thread groups
3. in thread group 1 - add JDBC request "set enable_result_cache_for_session to off;"   query type (IMPORTANT) - Update statement (others didn't work for me)
4. in thread group 2 - put all other JDBC requests

TestPlan settings:
[image]
Cache off jdbc request:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this only once per cluster, not for each query so if you set `enable_result_cache_for_session` to `false` using i.e. [Query Editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html) it should be applied until you set it back to `true`

If you have to do this with JMeter I can only think of connecting to RedShift instance over SSH

[image: RedShift SSH]

You can do this using JMeter [SSH Command Sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) (you will need to install it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)) and set the parameter via relevant SSH command.